# How to convert continuous values into discrete values by equivalent partitioning in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, divide

I want to transform continuous values of a dataframe column into discrete values by equivalent partioning.
For example, the following is my `input`.

I want to divide the continuous value in column `a` into 3 intervals.

`Input:`

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 2.4, 2.5, 4.1]})
```

`Output:`

```
     a
0  1.1
1  1.2
2  1.3
3  2.4
4  2.5
5  4.1
```

In column  `a`, the minimum value is 1.1, the maximum value is `4.1`, I want to divide it into `3 intervals`.

As you see, the size of each interval is equal to `(4.1-1.1)/3 = 1.0`. So I can regard all the values in the interval of `[1.1, 2.1)` (bigger or equal to `1.1` and less than `2.1` ) as `0`, all the values in the interval of `[2.1, 3.1)` as `1`, and all the values in the interval of `[3.1, 4.1]` as `2`.

So here is my expected result.

`Expected:`

```
   a
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  1
5  2
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html) with parameter `right = False` as:

```
pd.cut(df.a, bins=3, labels=np.arange(3), right=False)

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
5    2
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (3, int64): [0 < 1 < 2]
```

---

How the binning is done:

```
pd.cut(df.a, bins=3, right=False)

0      [1.1, 2.1)
1      [1.1, 2.1)
2      [1.1, 2.1)
3      [2.1, 3.1)
4      [2.1, 3.1)
5    [3.1, 4.103)
Name: a, dtype: category
Categories (3, interval[float64]): [[1.1, 2.1) < [2.1, 3.1) < [3.1, 4.103)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `np.digitize` function and define the variation of bins to assign labels

```
np.digitize(df.a,np.arange(1.1,4.1,1)) - 1
```

Out:

```
array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2], dtype=int64)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us do `diff` and `cumsum`

```
df.a=(~np.isclose(df.a.diff(),0.1)).cumsum()-1 # since it is float I am using close 
df
Out[395]: 
   a
0  0
1  0
2  0
3  1
4  1
5  2
```